# Why do WiFi Direct peers vanish

Tags: android, p2p, wifi-direct, wifimanager

The question is based on an observation I made while playing around with the WiFi Direct Demo Application rolled out by google.

Why does the shown list of Available peers tend to shorten even when the WifiDirect enabled devices are in close range? However, if I manually 'search' for available peers again, the list of peers grows. Well the latter seems a normal behavior, whereby `mManager.discoverPeers()` is called first which subsequently invokes a call to the callback function `onPeersAvailable()` to give a new set of peers if changed.

But why would `onPeersAvailable()` get called when the phones are just idle but still nearby and thus shorten the list of peers?

Thanks

Comment: I suspect its because radio is basically pretty unreliable.  There are always going to be occasional dropouts.

Comment: Yes that makes sense, but does that mean that the discovery process triggers the other devices to start sending out sth like a beacon msg?which in turn calls onPeersAvailable().